# Count the number of bytes in Hex values in Python

Tags: count, hex, byte

I'm new to programming and learning a bit of Python for some engineering related activities so sorry if I'm asking this question in the wrong way.

Is there a way to calculate the number of bytes represented by hex values in Python.

For example, if I have 0x38 (1 byte) and 0x04 (1 byte) is there a way to put these into Python and say the total number of bytes is 2?

Thank you!

Comment: What will your input look like? `["0x38", "0x04", "0xffff"]`?

Comment: '\x01\x3c' etc.
However since this post, I've tried using the len function and it seems to be working well. Is this the correct way? For example len('\x03\xff')=2

Comment: It's correct if `len('\x0000ff') == 3` is not a problem for you.